# Use SymfonyContainer in a decorated service

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm developing a module for PS1.7.8.6 which add datas to a stock movement. In order to do that, I have decorate the PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Stock\StockManager following the doc.

I don't know if the decoration was made in a good way because the stock movement in the BO still use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Stock\StockManager instead of my class CustomStockManager.

But in my module, if I call my CustomStockManager, the movement is not made. I've found that the function SymfonyContainer::getInstance(); return null so the function saveMovement() return false.

Is there a way to know why the SymfonyContainer return null ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution. The function SymfonyContainer::getInstance() return null because the function is called from an ajax.php file which call a function from the module.

To resolve it, first, I have put the function getKernel() from [this article](https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2018/05/how-to-work-with-the-symfony-kernel-anywhere-in-prestashop-1-7/) in the file mymodule.php.

Then, il my CustomStockManager, in the function saveMovement(), I have change this

```
$sfContainer = SymfonyContainer::getInstance();
if (null === $sfContainer) {
    return false;
}
```

To

```
$sfContainer = SymfonyContainer::getInstance();
if (null === $sfContainer) {
    $moduleObj = Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule');
    $sfContainer = $moduleObj->getKernel()->getContainer();
}
```

And because there is no context and so no user to to the movement, at the beginning of the function I add :

```
if (is_null(Context::getContext()->employee)) {
    $context = Context::getContext();
    $context->employee = new Employee(1);
}
```

It works now but I think this is not the best way to do that. So I will change my ajax.php file in a controller for the module.